df['articleID'] = df.astype({'articleID': int}) when I am using this query getting error as ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
what would be possible issue?
I want to change datatype of columns in data frame
I have tried below codes only last one gives error all others are working but not changing datatype of columns even if below code is run datatype remains object for these columns.
#df[['articleID','sizeCode','productGroup']].astype(int)

#df['rrp'].astype(float)

#changed datatypes of variables as required

df=df.astype({'articleID': int,
               'rrp': float,'sizeCode': int,
              'productGroup': int,
             })

Below code gives Value Error: Columns must be same length as key
df['articleID'] = df.astype({'articleID': int})
 


Works fine for me with df = pd.DataFrame({'articleID': [str(i) for i in range(4)]}). Please make a [mre]. For specifics, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and see [ask] if you want more tips.

"all others are working but not changing datatype of columns" - Yeah, that's to be expected since you're not saving the result.
